# Replace row values with sequence value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this,

```
                     img
0 6479965c_2019_04_15_20_26_25_90.jpg
1 6479965c_2019_04_15_20_26_25_92.jpg
2 6479965c_2019_04_15_20_26_25_93.jpg
3 6479965c_2019_04_15_20_26_25_96.jpg
4 6479965c_2019_04_15_20_26_26_10.jpg
....
```

How can I replace each value to,

```
"foo" + str(counter) + ".jpg"
```

I iterated,

```
counter = 1
for i in df['img']:
    i = "foo_" + str(counter)  + ".jpg"
    counter += 1
```

but it does not work.

Comment: It already has `.jpg`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code, pandas can do:

```
df['img'] = 'foo_' + (df.index + 1).astype(str) + '.jpg'
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
            img
0 foo_1.jpg.jpg
1 foo_2.jpg.jpg
2 foo_3.jpg.jpg
3 foo_4.jpg.jpg
4 foo_5.jpg.jpg
```

Comment: how to get rid of 6479965c_2019_04_15_20_26_25_90 this part ?? I want to have my own counter which starts from 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is setting `i` is not going to change the original value take a look at this example I need to get the index of the current element to set so I'll use enumerate and for efficiency not going to use the constant variable instead add onto the index value

```py
for index, item in enumerate(df['img']):
    df['img'][index] = "foo_" + str(index+1)  + ".jpg
```

EDIT: Just realized you got a dictionary so you dont have to use enumerate

```py
for index, item in df['img'].items():
    df['img'][index] = "foo_" + str(index+1)  + ".jpg
```